# No Login with facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication, token

hi i have a problem with fb login in android app.
When i have the facebook application installed on my phone  the login on myapp does not work:

`{Session state: CREATED, token: token {AccessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions: []}`

but if uninstall the facebook app, my login app works fine. why?any idea?Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: have you logged in ,in your facebook before trying to login in to facebook from your application?

Comment: yes i have,ask me always a permission but not login (no take a facebook token)